# SQL command error for multiple value conditions in another table column

Tags: sql

We want to add a new column which values are depending by lots of conditions

For example, there are lots of bin numbers refer to different country like this bin number table

```
Start_Bin     End_Bin     Country_Code
---------------------------------------
4976999       4971000     US
4986999       4990000     UK
4920000       4929999     US
```

And we want to create a new column of country code in a table with conditions based on this table

This is our SQL code, which is not allowed by SQL Server :(

```
ALTER TABLE temp.we_are_foreigners__table 
ADD COLUMNS 
    CASE
        WHEN 
           (CAST(temp.we_are_foreigners__table.accountno AS int) 
                >= CAST(temp.visa_country_classify_table.start_binnumber AS int) 
            AND CAST(temp.we_are_foreigners__table.accountno AS int) 
                <= CAST(temp.visa_country_classify_table.end_binnumber AS int) ) 
        THEN temp.visa_country_classify_table.country_code
        WHEN 
            (CAST(temp.we_are_foreigners__table.accountno AS int) 
                >= CAST(temp.mastercard_country_classify_table.start_binnumber AS int) 
            AND CAST(temp.we_are_foreigners__table.accountno AS int) 
                <= CAST(temp.mastercard_country_classify_table.end_binnumber AS int) ) 
        THEN temp.mastercard_country_classify_table.country_code
    END As Country_String
FROM 
    temp.visa_country_classify_table, 
    temp.mastercard_country_classify_table, 
    temp.we_are_foreigners__table
;
```

What's the proper SQL command of doing this, what's the problem?

Comment: which database are you using?  The different tags you have listed (`mysql`,`sql`,`sql-server`,`postgresql`,`sqlite`) all have/support different syntaxes

Comment: Did you try a stored procedure ?

Comment: Removed all the different specific database tags; re-add the one you're actually using.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate out your alter table from your update. You also need to specify how you are joining your tables.

Here is an example, with an assumed join condition:

```
ALTER Table temp.we_are_foreigners__table add Country_String varchar(100)

update f set Country_string= 
    CASE
        WHEN 
        CAST(f.accountno AS int) >= CAST(v.start_binnumber AS int) 
            AND CAST(f.accountno AS int) <= CAST(v.end_binnumber AS int)  
        THEN m.country_code
        WHEN 
            CAST(f AS int) >= CAST(m.start_binnumber AS int) 
            AND CAST(f.accountno AS int) <= CAST(m.end_binnumber AS int) 
        THEN m.country_code
    END 
FROM  temp.we_are_foreigners__table f
join  temp.visa_country_classify_table v on v.countryID=f.CountryID
join  temp.mastercard_country_classify_table m on m.countryID=f.CountryID
```